# Can DOMContentLoaded be fired after load event?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, browser

As far as I know, window load event is fired after DOMContentLoaded event. But I have seen a different case. Please explain me what could cause this case.

Is this Chrome's bug? Or can the sequence change?

[image: DOMContentLoaded after Load]

(Chrome Version 54.0.2840.99 m)

Comment: is that a page `load` event? or some other resource `load` event?

Comment: According to Google, the red line depicts `load` event, furthermore, there is only one red line, so you may guess.

Comment: chrome 54? It's about 1 year old...

Comment: @Kaiido, So do you mean chrome 54 has bugs? Is that version the problem? You imply DOMContentLoaded is fired only after load event, don't you?